# Get installed CocoaPods version

Tags: cocoapods

How do I get the version of [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) I have installed on my Mac?
I could run `sudo gem install cocoapods` but, I want to get the installed version without reinstalling CocoaPods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just posting this for people to see in the future, but you can simply check the version by running the following command:

`$ pod --version`

Answer (score 2):

## Integrity Check

There is more to `Cocoapod` version than the pod gem:

**Pods**

```bash
pod --version                    #Show the version of the tool
gem list --local | grep pods     #Show the version of all related tools
```

**Ruby**
To ensure compatibility across development environments, you may want to look at

```bash
ruby --version                   #Print the version of Ruby
gem --version                    #Print version of RubyGems, package manager for Ruby
```

**Xcode**
Finally, to get the proper Xcode tools across development environments, also look at:

```bash
xcode-select --version           #Print the version of xcode-select
xcode-select -p                  #Print the path of the active developer directory
gem list --local | grep xcode    #Print xcodeproj version (a tool also used by pods)
```

Answer (score 0):

For full detail Use : `$ gem which cocoapods`

It will give `<Folder Version> & <Location>`