# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

i am trying to run a AWS Cognito service project in which i have added the AWS SDK for iOS but after adding it and trying to run it it shows me the below shown error in the image

[ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJUDC.png)

when i crawl it on internet and found some cocoapods install instructions so after trying that i got some other error like below

```
aparajita:Objective-C Aparajita$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository
aparajita:Objective-C Aparajita$ gem install cocoapods
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository
aparajita:Objective-C Aparajita$ gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org/

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
aparajita:Objective-C Aparajita$ gem source -a rubygems.org
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
rubygems.org is not a URI
aparajita:Objective-C Aparajita$ gem source -r rubygems.org
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
source rubygems.org not present in cache
```

i have tried it all but still above log i got from the console . if any one have any solution on this please let me know, thanks

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` on the Command-line?

Comment: ran it but showing message : -bash: bundle: command not found

Comment: Are you in the right directory, when running this command? Seems like there is an error with the bundle command and not with rails.

Comment: Did you notice *warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777*?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect yes i saw it, it seems like some access is less to me for Read Write Excute mode. it is like or is there some other meaning for this message?

Comment: *Insecure world writable dir* is definitely a security risk. As for your question, you seem to have installation issues, clearly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30041614/218152

Answer (score 49):

I am facing the same problem and I resolved it by issuing using the following command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me too. I'm guessing its related to proxy or dns settings on my machine. Thank you.

Comment: You welcme @Raviteja_DevObal

Comment: Awesome Solution, Thanks :)

Comment: You welcome  :) – steveSarsawa

Answer (score 13):

OK, I just had this problem. If anyone seems to have this problem DO NOT change directories.

Load up terminal and straight away add the line -

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

This command worked for me

```
  sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: This simply repeats the highest voted answer. Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with same issue 1 week, finally this works for me

**Disable IPv6 and try again** with **sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org**

Issues seems with network

Few more details give on rugby gems forum - https://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/31074-timeout-error

Comment: In my case the VPN was blocking the installation. So turning off the VPN was a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used VPN, because http://rubygems.org was unavailable, as soon as I switched the VPN on sudo gem install cocoapods worked

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Xcode installed in your Mac. After opening for the first time you need to accept the Terms & Condition and may need to install some components. Once it is setup and working, then install Pod:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried everything above did not work. I did the following.

note: make sure you have installed the xcode and also you opened it to accept the terms.

1. install brew using this command:

```
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. install ruby using this command:

```
    brew install ruby
```

3. after installing the ruby, you will see something like that

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
in the terminal, this will add the ruby to your path so run it.

```
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

4. install the cocoapods:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not worked for me

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Ruby was installed for me by default. Cross checked it with this

```
which gem
```

I tried the brew way of installing cocoapods

```
brew install cocoapods
```

The installation suspended when I was on VPN. I disconnected VPN and then brew way of installation worked for me.

I did verify the installation of cocoapods through brew by the following command

```
brew list
```

I was able to find the cocoapods in the list.