# Why isn't this cocoapods update working?

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to update cocoapods (somehow I have a version before version 1.0) and I'm getting this error: `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz) What is this error and how can I fix it?`

Comment: I thought about uninstalling and trying to reinstall but I'm worried then I might end up with no Cocoapods at all

Comment: this link maybe could give you some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784844/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-cocoapods-0-in-any-repository